# setting UIImageView rounded corners with AFNetworking setImageWithURL:

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, calayer, afnetworking

This works when not using AFNetworking's category method on the UIImageView, but I realize AF is probably overwriting whatever is done since this is happening async:

this is in my custom UITableViewCell (self being the cell):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:video.thumbnail];    
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:url
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"]];
// not working
CALayer *layer = [self.imageView layer];
[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

tried placing it before the call to setImageWithURL as well.

Here is what I have NOW and it is not rounding the corners:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_video.thumbnail];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIImage *placeHolder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"];
__weak UIImageView *imageView = self.thumbnail;

[self.thumbnail setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeHolder success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

    imageView.image = image;
    // round the edges of the video thumbnail
    CALayer *layer = [imageView layer];
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer setCornerRadius:8.0];

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"couldn't load image: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

Comment: when you download image from a url, it takes some time depend on the speed of internet, in this case, imageView is not properly loaded image from url. You should use block or Async to first download the image completely then extract layer from it.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
__weak UIImageView *imageView = self.imageView;
[self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    imageView.image = image;
    CALayer *layer = imageView.layer;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
} failure:NULL];
```

Comment: That's the one I was talking about in my answer. :)

Comment: @MarkW Did you `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: This one is working. But if added to uitbleviewcell image uitableview not smoothly scrolling. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used AFNetworking but I see that there is a version of the `setImageWithURL` method that takes a "success" block. Try using that version and in the "success" block, update the image view`s layer.

Answer (score 0):

The SDWebImage library, available at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, includes the method:

- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock;

The following code is an example implementation from a project I'm working on, with a rather large rounded corner.  I've used both AFNetworking and SDWebImage in the same project.

```
    __weak UIImageView * theImageView = self.imageView;

    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:user.imgurl] placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
        // I only attempt to apply this if an image has been returned.
        if (image) {
            theImageView.image = image;
            CALayer * layer = theImageView.layer;
            layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
        }

    }];
```